# Instability Problem in Normalized Least Mean Squares (NLMS) Adaptive Algorithm

Tags: adaptive-filters, equalization, adaptive-algorithms, least-squares

I have been used NLMS algorithm to equalize 4x4 MIMO signals, but the bit-error-rate (BER) after equalization is unstable with iterations. I don't know if it is the normal behavior of the adaptive algorithm or some parameters in the algorithm needed to be adjusted.

the updated equation used for this algorithm is:

$$
\mathbf{w}[n+1] = \mathbf{w}[n] + \mu \mathbf{x}[n]\frac{ e^*[n]}{\mathbf{x}^H[n] \mathbf{x}[n] + \gamma}
$$

where $\mathbf{w}$ is the weights, $\mu$ is the step size, $\mathbf{x}$ is the input signal, $e$ is the error and $\gamma$ is a small positive number.

in my simulation, I used these values:

number of weights=100, mu=0.001 and gamma=0.001

the constellation of the desired signal and output signal from channel

(the length of the channel filter is 400) and the BER figures are shown:
[image]

is the instability normal for this algorithm?. Although I have tried different values for filter length and the step size, the BER is still unstable

Comment: **Unstable** ? Or do you mean **not Converging** ? The oscillation (variation) from sample to sample in the BER plot is a typical of LMS type of adaptive filters when the convergence is slow. Which can be due to a number of factors, other than an implementation error,  such as non-stationary input signal or improper step size $\mu$.

Comment: yes, i mean the oscillation from sample to sample. even when i increased the step size these oscillations still exist.

Comment: how to know if the input signal is non-stationary? at first, i generate random binary data, data modulated using 4-QAM then the data passed through the channel with length 400

Comment: If your channel length is 400 and your adaptive filter is length 100, how do you expect it to equalize at all?

Comment: @Peter Actually, increasing the filter length decreases the min BER at the expense of increasing these oscillations.

Comment: Mai, the issue is that the adaptive filter is aiming to undo the effect of the channel --- effectively "inverting" the channel response. So trying to invert a 400-tap FIR with a 100-tap FIR just won't happen (fully).  Try (as an example) setting the channel to be an AR(4) system, rather than an MA(400), and see if things improve.

Comment: I repeat the simulation using filter length of 400 but the problem of variations still exists. are there any conditions for the input signal to avoid these variations?

Comment: @M.F. this is years later, but if still an issue for other folks, I would suggest looking at the $x^H[n]*x[n]$ calculation. These should be calculated as a dot product. Omitting that step can lead to instability.